# Swift combine error: method on 'Publisher' requires .Failure' (aka 'WeatherError') and 'Never' be equivalent

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, combine

I am learning Swift Combine now, found quite easy video tutorial, however for some reason I get error when I try to use my enum in PassthroughSubject<Int, WeatherError>()

Check this code:

```
import Combine 

enum WeatherError: Error {
   case thingsJustHappen
   
}
let weatherPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Int, WeatherError>()


let subscriber = weatherPublisher
   .filter {$0 > 10}
   .sink { value in
       print("\(value)")
   }

weatherPublisher.send(10)
weatherPublisher.send(30)
```

".filter" is highlighted and the error is:

```
Referencing instance method 'sink(receiveValue:)' on 'Publisher' 
requires the types 'Publishers.Filter<PassthroughSubject<Int, WeatherError>>.Failure' 
(aka 'WeatherError') and 'Never' be equivalent
```

Surprisingly this code works in the video tutorial. How can I make my WeatherError and Never to be equivalent???

Answer (score 44):

You need to provide both handlers, the completion one, and the value one:

```swift
let subscriber = weatherPublisher
    .filter { $0 > 10 }
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }, receiveValue: { value in
       print("\(value)")
    })
```

This is needed because the single-argument `sink`, is available only for publishers that can never fail:

```swift
extension Publisher where Self.Failure == Never {
    /// ... many lines of documentation omitted
    public func sink(receiveValue: @escaping ((Self.Output) -> Void)) -> AnyCancellable
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that,  I just simply followed the tutorial which  is a bit old (July 2019). I was just thinking If it may be the reason why is not working for me. I need to read more about sink and receiveCompletion/receiveValue. Thanks again Cristik.

Comment: @Piotr979, yeah, outdated tutorials are sometimes worse than no tutorials at all :)

Comment: Makes no sense but works!

Comment: Is there an easy way to convert the publisher into one which cannot fail?

Comment: @aehlke see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58227096/set-a-given-publishers-failure-type-to-never-in-combine

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you change the type to **Never**:

```
let weatherPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
```

Or create a new Published variable:

```
@Published var weather = 0

let weatherPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Int, WeatherError>()

let weatherSubscriber = weather
   .filter { $0 > 10 }
   .sink { print($0) }

let subscriber = weatherPublisher
   .sink { [weak self] value in
       self?.weather = value
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

in  Xcode 13 & iOS 15.4 this code needed brackets to compile.

```
extension Publisher where Self.Failure ==  Never {
    // because the publisher can NEVER FAIL - by design!
    public  func sink(receiveValue: @escaping ((Self.Output) -> Void)) -> AnyCancellable {  }
}
```

Comment: Is this a reply to my answer? If yes, note that the code snippet was extracted from the Combine interface, so it's expected to contain only the declarations, not the implementations.