# Swift combine Convert Publisher type

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm exploring Combine Swift with this project https://github.com/sgl0v/TMDB
and I'm trying to replace its imageLoader with something that supports Combine: https://github.com/JanGorman/MapleBacon

The project has a function that returns the type `AnyPublisher<UIImage?, Never>`.
But the imageLoader MapleBacon library returns the type `AnyPublisher<UIImage, Error>`.

So I'm trying to convert types with this function:

```
func convert(_ loader: AnyPublisher<UIImage, Error>) -> AnyPublisher<UIImage?, Never> {
    // here.
}
```

I actually found a question that is kinda similar to mine, but the answers weren't helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58234908/3231194

---

What I've tried to so far (Matt's answer to the linked question).

The sample project has this function:

```
func loadImage(for movie: Movie, size: ImageSize) -> AnyPublisher<UIImage?, Never> {
        return Deferred { return Just(movie.poster) }
            .flatMap({ poster -> AnyPublisher<UIImage?, Never> in
                guard let poster = movie.poster else { return .just(nil) }
                let url = size.url.appendingPathComponent(poster)
                let a = MapleBacon.shared.image(with: url)
                    .replaceError(with: UIImage(named: "")!) // <----
            })
            .subscribe(on: Scheduler.backgroundWorkScheduler)
            .receive(on: Scheduler.mainScheduler)
            .share()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

if I do `replaceError`,

I get the type `Publishers.ReplaceError<AnyPublisher<UIImage, Error>>`

---

BUT, I was able to solve this one, by extending the library.

```
extension MapleBacon {
    public func image(with url: URL, imageTransformer: ImageTransforming? = nil) -> AnyPublisher<UIImage?, Never> {
      Future { resolve in
        self.image(with: url, imageTransformer: imageTransformer) { result in
          switch result {
          case .success(let image):
            resolve(.success(image))
          case .failure:
            resolve(.success(UIImage(named: "")))
          }
        }
      }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson IDK, just a challenge, like the whole sample project has that type. I too want an optional UIImage versus an UIImage with Error publisher in a ViewModel (just like in the sample project).

Comment: That seems like a perfect duplicate target. How didn't those answers solve your problem?

Comment: @DávidPásztor See the comment in the answer to the linked question. I actually tried it, but it seems it's just getting more complicated for me. One solution that I'm looking at now is to just extend the library.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried from that post? What has "got more complicated"? Matt's answer should do the job.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper. See my edit. I added my current solution too.

Comment: Side note: rather than changing the code in `loadImage`, I think it's better to create your own conformance of the protocol `ImageLoaderServiceType`, and pass that to the initialiser of `MoviesUseCase`. Just saying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to `map` a `UIImage` to a `UIImage?`. The sensible way to do this is of course to wrap each element in an optional.

Then, you try to turn a publisher that sometimes produces errors to a publisher that `Never` produces errors. You `replaceError(with:)` an element of your choice. What element should you replace errors with? The natural answer, since your publisher now publishes *optional* images, is `nil`! Of course, `assertNoFailure` works syntactically too, but you might be downloading an image here, so errors are very likely to happen...

Finally, we need to turn this into an `AnyPublisher` by doing `eraseToAnyPublisher`

```
MapleBacon.shared.image(with: url)
    .map(Optional.some)
    .replaceError(with: nil)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: Also, I appreciate the explanation!