# Converting Publisher's error type to Never in Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a Publisher

`var subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Error>()`

I want to convert it to

`PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>`

Is there anyway to achieve this ?

Edit - More Details

I do not want the Publisher to complete and the linked answer did not work because catch still completes the publisher.

Comment: Why a `PassthroughSubject` specifically? Does an `AnyPublisher<Int, Never>` not work for you? If it does, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58227096/set-a-given-publishers-failure-type-to-never-in-combine).

Comment: Because my code is using PassthroughSubject but of course that can be changed. I have already tried this link. The problem is that the catch still requires another publisher. What i want is just to somehow ignore all the error and convert Error to Never so that it can be used downstream.

Comment: and additionally i do not want the publisher to complete

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: Catch the error if one comes. Now you can turn the downstream type into whatever you like. https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsErrorHandlers/operatorscatch.html

Comment: @matt From your link "The Output type of the publisher must match the Output type of the upstream pipeline." If i have understood it correctly that means <Int, Error> cannot be converted to <Int, Never> for downstream. However this is exactly what i want or am i misunderstanding.

Comment: I want to convert <Int,Error> to <Int,Never> so the downstream subscribers only see <Int,Never> and the publisher continues publishing.

Comment: The output type is the same (`Int` in your example), not the error type.  You may need to combine catch with `share` https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsErrorHandlers/operatorsretry.html

Comment: I really don't know what you mean "cannot be converted to `<Int, Never>`". That is exactly what you _can_ do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of using `catch` to turn an `<Int, Error>` into an `<Int, Never>`:

```
import UIKit
import Combine
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Error>()
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.subject
            .catch { what in
                Empty(completeImmediately:false)
            }
            .sink {print($0)}
            .store(in: &self.storage)
    }
}
```

If you send `1` to the passthrough subject now, you get `1` out the end. But if you send an error to the passthrough subject, no error arrives at the end; the pipeline end type is `<Int, Never>`.

However, do note that you can then never send another value. This has nothing to do with the pipeline; it's because once you send an error through a Subject, that Subject is dead. There's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Hmm I thought that somehow there might be possibility that i can prevent the death of subject. This means that now i have redesign my subject. Probably need to add a dedicated subject for errors so that i do not have to send an error through a subject but instead sending error as an event.

Comment: Well that is what a Result is for.